# bleeding of brakes on my elantra 2005

Tags: brakes, hyundai, elantra, bleeding

I'm about to bleed my brakes and replace all the fluid... Haven't done this in decades. In the old days I'd start from the right rear, go to left rear, then right front and left front last. I have seen on some videos some folks who do the entire right side first (both back and then front) and then go over to the left (driver's side) and start at the rear left. Can anyone comment on whether this is the new way to do stuff or it simply does not matter... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bleeding the brakes on the Hyundais & Kias with ESC is a bit different than bleeding them the way we used to back in the day. One of the things you'll need *to do it correctly* is a [Hi-Scan (Pro) tool](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hi%20scan%20pro%20(hyundai%20%26%20kia)%20tool). Not exactly something you'll have laying around in your toolbox.

To properly bleed the brakes, do the following:

**NOTE:** When pressure bleeding, do not depress the brake pedal. Recommended fluid: DOT3 or DOT4

1. Clean then remove the reservoir cap and fill the brake reservoir with clean brake fluid.
2. Connect a clear plastic tube to the wheel cylinder bleeder plug and insert the other end of the tube into a half filled clear plastic bottle.
3. Connect the Hi-Scan (Pro) to the data link connector (DLC) located underneath the dash panel.
4. Select and operate according to the instructions on the Hi-Scan (Pro) screen.

**CAUTION:** You must obey the maximum operating time of the ABS motor with the Hi-Scan (Pro) to prevent the motor pump from burning out.

5. Select Hyundai vehicle diagnosis
6. Select vehicle name.
7. Select Anti-Lock Brake system.
8. Select air bleeding mode.
9. Press "YES" to operate motor pump and solenoid valve.
10. Wait 60 seconds before operating the air bleeding again. (If not, you may damage the motor.)
11. Pump the pedal several times and then loosen the bleeder screw until fluid starts to run out without bubbles (or clean brake fluid if flushing the system). Then close the bleeder screw.
12. Repeat  from step 5 until there are no more bubbles in the fluid for each wheel.

I've seen several different lists of which wheel should go first, second, etc. To my knowledge, you should work from the wheel which is furthest away from the master cylinder, then the second furthest, and so on until you've finished all four wheels.

As an alternate method, you can let the brakes gravity bleed. You don't want to pump the brakes with any method because you run the distinct chance of ruining the master cylinder in the process. Gravity bleeding involves just popping open the bleeder valve and letting the brake fluid bleed into a blottle through clear tubing. When the fluid runs clean, that wheel is complete. This takes a lot of time to complete and you have to be patient. Ensure you keep the master cylinder fluid level up to full or you'll have to start back at the beginning and do it all over again.

Comment: And what if i don't have ESC?

Comment: @thurgood - I don't know when Hyundai started using ESC, but I believe they've been using it on their cars for quite some time. My '08 Azera has it. I'm pretty sure your Elantra has it because these are the instructions which came up for all Elantras for 2005. If for some reason it doesn't, then just gravity bleeding should work, but will take a lot longer to accomplish.

Comment: removing the cap on the reservoir helps when gravity bleeding.

Comment: @Ben - How correct you are, sir :o)