# Elantra 1.6GLS 2003 - Brake pedal goers to the floor after changing rear brake line and bleeding

Tags: brakes, hyundai, abs

How can I bleed the Antilock Braking System (ABS) circuits on my 2003 Hyundai Elantra?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! By "vent" do you actually mean *bleed*? As in , bleed the air out of the system?

Comment: [Possibly useful?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41085/bleeding-of-brakes-on-my-elantra-2005)

Comment: Yes, I meant bleeding the unit.

Comment: Proper bleeding of the abs requires a scan tool that can perform the bleeding functions